# Data type mismatch circle object

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to make a circle object that accepts a float value as an argument for the radius of my circle, and I'm not too good with data types so I figured if I just made everything a float I wouldn't have any mismatch errors, so I did this below:

```
public class Circle {
protected float Circle;
protected float radius;

// Constructor
public Circle(float newRadius) {
    radius = newRadius;

}

// Observers
public float getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public float perimeter() {

    {
        return ((2) * (3.14) * (radius));
    }

}
```

and it's returning a "Type mismatch cannot convert double to float" error on the line where I multiple for the perimeter of the circle. Could someone please explain what I'm doing incorrectly to me?

It can be simply ignored by casting it to float, but then it doesn't return the proper value I'm supposed to be getting of "31.400002"

Comment: Literals with decimal digits are by default doubles. Cast the literal to a float.

Comment: extremely important bit of convention: do **not** use variables with identical names as your class. Class names start with upper case, variables start with lower case (and multiple words use the camelCasingConvention after the first word in Java)

Comment: or change the order to `return radius * 3.14 * 2;`  no parenthesis are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3.14` has the type `double`, so the entire expression `((2) * (3.14) * (radius))` is promoted to a `double`. You can change `3.14` to a `float` literal by appending `F`:

```
return ((2) * (3.14F) * (radius));
```

Comment: so is any decimal value automatically considered as a double? If so then what are the parameters for the type float?

Comment: literally that. Add an F to the number. Floats have very poor precision, and generally still lead to compound errors in calculations, where doubles have those errors in fairly deep decimals.

Comment: @SamShaheen Yes, if a decimal doesn't have the `F` (or `f`) suffix it's a double. I don't understand your second question...